# how to get user location on nativeScript app

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

i'm developing a nativeScript application,in my app I need to get user's location,I have already tried to fix it reading the documentation, but I couldn't fix it. can anyone help with this

Answer (score 2):

You need [nativescript-geolocation](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation) plugin and the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/hardware/location) cover that too.

Comment: i have used geolocation plugin but when app building ,it give this error : Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

Comment: Are you using any other plugin in your app that might also be using google play services library? Did you try [this step](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-geolocation#version-conflicts--google-play-services) from ReadMe?

Comment: yes, i have used firebase plugin,  i think it have conflicts with geolocation plugin do you know how to update the version of  google-services plugin  i think it might be the problem